# Why is the user not being prompted to enter values for the variables which have an input() statement tagged with them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, python-idle

In this code below, when I enter a multi-line input for the variable 'x', the successive variables automatically assign themselves a value (even when I want the user to enter them (I've also distinctly written the input() statements for each of these variables)) (see below). How does this happen? Why do the successive lines inputted for 'x' automatically get stored in 'y', 'z' and the other variables?

```
>>> x=input()
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
>>> print(x)
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>>> y=input()
>>> print(y)
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>>> z=input()
>>> print(z)
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>>> a=input()
>>> print(a)
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
>>> b=input()
>>> print(b)
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
>>> c=input()
>>> print(c)
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
```

Comment: That's unusual... In my REPL, it's seemingly impossible to enter multiple lines for one `input` prompt. Are you using IDLE or something?

Comment: @Kevin
I am using an IDLE.

Comment: It might be possible if you're pasting a block of lines from the clipboard.

Comment: @khelwood
I'm exactly doing that. But unable to understand the mechanism behind this happening.

Comment: I assume input() reads the buffer until the next `\n`, so when you call input again the buffer isn't empty and it continues reading from there.

Comment: I recommend pyperclip for dealing with the clipboard.

Comment: @VincentSavard
That seems to be a reasonable possibility. Thank you!

Comment: @khelwood
Okay, would certainly consider your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is that python reads code and data a line at a time.  The detailed behavior is different for the interactive interpreter and IDLE's simulation thereof.  At a Win10 console, pasting 3 of the lines above does the following (in 3.5.0) without the user hitting hitting Enter.

```
>>> input()
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
'73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934'
>>> 96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>>> 85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>>>
```

The first line is taken and echoed as the input response.  Subsequent lines are interpreted as code, in particular as int literal statements.

In IDLE, when user code is running, the Enter key sends typed or pasted characters to the user process as simulated stdin.  Compiled code is sent to the user process separately, tagged as code, not data, so text pasted as an stdin stream is not seen as code.

Comment: I think I got an idea of what you want to say here (pardon me for my being a novice in Python). Thank you!